# How to tell if string is an image or not

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, find

I'm extracting the icon path from the .desktop files.

Sometimes the files contain the absolute path to the file i.e

```
Icon=/snap/spotify/41/usr/share/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-128.png
```

Other times its just the name of the file no ext

```
Icon=spotify-linux-128
```

I'm currently searching the /usr/share/icons/hicolor folders for the icon name. But when the icon path is absolute and points to a file i'm getting no results as find is looking in the wrong location.

Is there a way to tell in my bash script if a string is an image?

I'm trying to check with:

```
file $iconpath
```

But obviously it errors if the path does not exist.

Is there a better way?

What would you do?

Comment: Just check if the string begins with a `/`?

Comment: My brains gone. Its 6am here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @muru pointed out.

The **obvious** solution is to check if the string starts /

i.e

```
if [[ $icon == /* ]] 
then
    echo "is a file path"
else
    echo "is not a file path"
fi
```

EDIT:

you can also do this to check if a file exists

```
if [ -a $icon ];
then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just chop off any path elements up to and including the last `/`

```
Icon=spotify-linux-128
echo ${Icon##*/}
spotify-linux-128

Icon=/snap/spotify/41/usr/share/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-128.png
echo ${Icon##*/}
spotify-linux-128.png
```

Then just throw a `*` on the end and feed the output to `find` with your specified search root

```
ls -1 sp*
spotify-linux-128
spotify-linux-128.png
spotify-linux-128.png.banana
spotify-linux-128.png.png

Icon=/snap/spotify/41/usr/share/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-128.png
fname=${Icon##*/}
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "$fname*" 

./spotify-linux-128.png.banana
./spotify-linux-128.png
./spotify-linux-128.png.png
```